# R number of sections in a structure

Tags: algorithm, r, math

Hi I'm working with big amounts of data in R and I need to check if a structure is formed by 1 or more sections. 
First I have a vector of ways

```
wayIds <- [way1, way2, way3, etc..]
```

Then I have a matrix with the first and last node of each way

```
endWays
           wayId firstNode lastNode
      [1,]  way1  node1      node2
      [2,]  way2  node4      node8
      [3,]  way3  node5      node1...
```

Both are big. So I need a way to determine if following the way connections the structure has 1 or more sections. For example

```
_|______/ 1 section (all the ways are connected)
_|__   ____/ 2 sections (NOT all the ways are connected)
```

So until now I can determine all the open ends (the ones at the end of a branch) for example, obviously if I have only two open nodes the solution is trivial. So, I need an effective way for determining if all the open nodes are connected each other without using a loop.

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you provide a small example with the desired result ?

Comment: ideally the sections grouped into vectors as    section1 <- [way2, way5 , way3], section2 <- [way1, way4] so I can perform further analysis. Thanks!

Comment: The way is directed or not ? I mean "node1 --> node2" is equal to "node2 --> node1" ? (i.e. ways are bidirectional)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to reinvent graph theory in R.  Take a look at the `igraph` package and `is.connected`.

Comment: yes, ways are bidirectional ("node1 --> node2" is equal to "node2 --> node1" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(igraph)

data <- read.table(text=
'wayId firstNode endNode
way1 node1 node2
way2 node2 node4
way3 node2 node3
way4 node4 node3
way5 node5 node6
way6 node5 node8
way7 node8 node7'
,header=TRUE,sep=' ')

# I reorder the columns before passing the data.frame to the function, 
# because the first 2 columns have to be node from and node to
g <- graph.data.frame(data[,c(2,3,1)],directed=FALSE)

# plot the graph (don't do it if your graph is really big)
plot.igraph(g,vertex.label=V(g)$name,
            vertex.size=30,vertex.label.cex=0.7,
            vertex.shape='square')

subGraphs <- decompose.graph(g,mode='strong')

for(i in 1:length(subGraphs)){
  subGraph <- subGraphs[[i]]

  message(paste('Sub graph:',i))
  # find vertices having just one connected node
  openVertices <- V(subGraph)[sapply(as.vector(V(subGraph)),FUN=function(v){length(E(subGraph)[from(v) | to(v)]) == 1})]

  message(paste('Open vertices:',toString(openVertices$name)))

  # plot the sub-graph (don't do it if your graph is really big)
  plot.igraph(subGraph,vertex.label=V(subGraph)$name,
              vertex.size=30,vertex.label.cex=0.7,
              vertex.shape='square')
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! just one more question, do you how can I get the open nodes of the graph (the elements that are connected just with one element)